# Ruby Bundler. How do I lock down all versions in Gemfile with working set from Gemfile.lock?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I want to set my `Gemfile` to use all the exact versions from a working `Gemfile.lock`.

What is the easiest way to do this?

I do not want to do it manually. Does `bundler` do this out of the box. If not, is there a gem for this?

To clarify, I have a `Gemfile` like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails'
```

I run `bundle install`, and I get a `Gemfile.lock` that works for me:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    pg (0.21.0)
    puma (3.10.0)
    rails (5.0.5)
      actioncable (= 5.0.5)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.5)
      actionpack (= 5.0.5)
      actionview (= 5.0.5)
      activejob (= 5.0.5)
      activemodel (= 5.0.5)
      activerecord (= 5.0.5)
      activesupport (= 5.0.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.0.5)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
```

Now I want a command that updates my `Gemfile` so that versions are specified:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg', '0.21.0'
gem 'puma', '3.10.0'
gem 'rails', '5.0.5'
```

Comment: maybe you could also explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @Kris clarified by changing my question.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to delete all the non-parent gems (e.g. `actioncable` etc.) under the `spec` key and then do a few find/replaces to convert it in to the correct format.

Comment: `bundle-auto-update` seems to be close to what I need, but it is not working for me.

Comment: You should definitely use [Bundler::LockfileParser](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/carlhuda/bundler/Bundler/LockfileParser) instead of some hand-made parser. This is implemented by bundler itself to read the `.lock` file. It would requires some tentatives but I am sure you will accomplish what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to reproduce your current `Gemfile.lock` in the `Gemfile` for another project, you can specify the exact version of your gems.

Let's assume that I have the following `Gemfile` in my Rails App:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
```

It generates the following `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    pg (0.21.0)
    puma (3.10.0)
    rails (5.0.5)
      actioncable (= 5.0.5)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.5)
      actionpack (= 5.0.5)
      actionview (= 5.0.5)
      activejob (= 5.0.5)
      activemodel (= 5.0.5)
      activerecord (= 5.0.5)
      activesupport (= 5.0.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.0.5)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
```

If I want to reproduce exactly the same situation in a new project, I will create a Gemfile with exact versions:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg', '0.21.0'
gem 'puma', '3.10.0'
gem 'rails', '5.0.5'
```

and so on..

You can refer to [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html)

#### Edit

After you changed the focus of your question, it seems you are trying to create a `Gemfile` from a `Gemfile.lock`.

You could have a look at [bundle --deployment](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE). I saw several SO questions complaining about the output.

So, if it is not 100% satisfactory, you can use the `Bundler::LockfileParser` and make your own script such as:

```
# test.rb
require 'bundler'

lockfile = Bundler::LockfileParser.new(Bundler.read_file('Gemfile.lock'))

specs = lockfile.specs
gems_hash = Hash.new.tap do |h|
  specs.each do |s|
    h[s.name] = {
      spec: s,
      dependencies: s.dependencies.map(&:name)
    }
  end
end

dependencies = gems_hash.keys && gems_hash.values.map { |h| h[:dependencies] }.flatten.uniq.sort

# Remove from the new Gemfile all gems installed as dependencies
dependencies.each { |dep| gems_hash.delete(dep) }

relevant_specs = gems_hash.values.map { |h| h[:spec] }

# I assume that by default you are installing from rubygems
puts "source 'https://rubygems.org'"
puts

relevant_specs.each do |s|
  if s.source.to_s =~ /https:\/\/rubygems.org/
    puts "gem '#{s.name}', '#{s.version}'" # eventually add "plaftform: :#{s.platform}"
  # I consider as only alternative a git source. 
  elsif s.source.is_a?(Bundler::Source::Git)
    uri = s.source.uri
    branch = s.source.branch
    ref = s.source.ref
    puts
    puts "git '#{uri}', branch: '#{branch}', ref: :#{ref} do"
    puts "  gem '#{s.name}'"
    puts "end"
    puts
  end
end
puts
```

I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mberlanda/54df3151292b9f0bd2a7b9bb00be8452) for reading easily.

You can create then your `Gemfile` by running:

```
$ ruby test.rb > Gemfile
```

Comment: used this answer to clarify my question. I'm starting with Gemfiles that are not specifying specific versions.

Comment: hey david, if this is the answer to your question, can you mark it as solved? or provide at least an upvote if it was helpful?

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I could tell from your attempt that my question wasn't clear though. So I think that's worth an upvote :)

Comment: would you need then to parse the Gemfile.lock in order to generate a new Gemfile with fixed gem versions?

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate it. And someone did a oneliner!

Answer (score 2):

You could always write it yourself :)

```
result = ""
File.readlines("Gemfile").each do |line|
  if line.strip.start_with?("gem") && !line.include?(",")
    name = line.match(/gem '(.+)'/)[1]
    output = `bundle info #{name}`
    version = output.match(/#{name} \((.+)\)/)[1]
    result << "  " if line.start_with?("  ")
    result << "gem '#{name}', '#{version}'\n"
  else
    result << line
  end
end
puts result
```

Works only with single quotes, though.

Answer (score 2):

to see gem names and versions in Gemfile like format see 

`bundle show`

On linux I use this quick and dirty snippet to convert to a format I can copy over  Gemfile.

`bundle show | ruby -ne 'puts $_.gsub(/ \* /,"gem \"").gsub(/ \(/,"\", \"~> ").gsub(/\)/,"\"")'`